# Building WYSIWYG in React, difficulty restoring selection range and creating link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, wysiwyg

I'm building a simple WYSIWYG editor in React and I've implemented all of the different button functionalities except this last one: selecting text and turning it into a hyperlink.

I need to preface this with: I'm not interested in answers like "just use React-Quill" or "just use react-draft-wysiwyg".

So the type of feature I'm trying to implement can be seen on https://quilljs.com/ - scroll down until you see the demo editor, then select some text, click the "link" button, and a secondary window will pop up containing a text input that allows you to enter a URL. Click SAVE, and the originally selected text will turn into a hyperlink.

I'm approaching this like so:

- Using `document.execCommand('createLink', false, myURL)` to handle the actual hyperlink creation
- When my url entry window pops up, I save the currently selected range by saving off the result of `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)`
- When the SAVE button is clicked, I restore the range by grabbing the document selection again, clearing all ranges with `sel.removeAllRanges()` and then calling `sel.addRange(mySavedRange)`

Note: all of this range saving and restoring is necessary, because when the user clicks on the text input on the pop-up window to enter a url, the document selection clears.

So here's what I'm seeing happen:

[image: The link shows up at the end of the text]

Instead of the selected text turning into a hyperlink (in this case I was selecting the word 'this',) the url is just thrown at the end of the line of text.

For reference, after trying my own code, I decided to try the functions implemented here: https://gist.github.com/dantaex/543e721be845c18d2f92652c0ebe06aa

I still see the same issue.

Any thoughts?

**An extra note**: I'm building an electron app, so I'm not as concerned with "cross-browser" compatibility. If it works in Chrome, then great!

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:** the issue was that the contenteditable div needed to be focused.

So I changed my approach:

1. Upon clicking "Save", instead of using the `document.execCommand` right away, I would update a global state field, like `enteredHyperlinkText` (I'm using [Reactn](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn))
2. I added a ref to my editor with `useRef` and an effect to my editor with `useEffect` (I'm using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)) the effect would only re-run when `enteredHyperlinkText` updates, and it will handle focusing on the editor, restoring the selection, and calling `document.execCommand`.

Note: focus the contenteditable div **before** restoring the selection.